# NetworkOnMainThreadException while executing Sql query using JDBC driver

Tags: android, jdbc

i am executing sql query using JDBC driver but it gives me NetworkOnMainThreadException.i have used a Asyntask for the network operation and mention Internet permission in the menifest file. below is my code for executing query

```
public class getLedger extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog progressDlg;
    private ResultSet rs;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDlg = new ProgressDialog(LedgerActivity.this);
        progressDlg.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDlg.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDlg.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
        progressDlg.setCancelable(false);
        progressDlg.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String ip = pref.getString("ip", "");
        String username = pref.getString("username", "");
        String password = pref.getString("password", "");
        String dbname = pref.getString("dbname", "");
        rs = new ExecuteQuery().selectdata(ip, username, password, strings[0], dbname);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                ArrayList<Ledger> ledgerlist = new ArrayList<>();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String accode = rs.getString("AC_CODE");
                    String acname = rs.getString("AC_NAME");
                    String acaddr = rs.getString("AC_ADD1");
                    String acmobile = rs.getString("AC_MOBILE");
                    String actype = rs.getString("AC_TYPE");
                    String amount = rs.getString("Amount");
                    String goldwt = rs.getString("GoldWt");
                    String silverwt = rs.getString("SilverWt");
                    ledgerlist.add(new Ledger(accode, acname, acaddr, acmobile, actype, amount, goldwt, silverwt));
                }
                LedgerAdapter adapter = new LedgerAdapter(LedgerActivity.this, ledgerlist);
                rcv_ledger.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not use JDBC drivers in Android applications. Let your Android application talk to a rest service, and the rest service to your database.

Comment: basically i am develepoing application for stock management system so it does not required any rest service. it is totally wifi base app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like call to ResultSet.next() uses `InputStream` under the hood to load row value or something like that.

So to avoid exception you need to return `ArrayList<Ledger>` from `doInBackground()` instead of parsing `ResultSet` in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: According to which JDBC documentation?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()

Comment: Nothing in those docs says it uses an `InputStream` under the hood (although a lot of implementations do in some form). The _"If an input stream is open for the current row, a call to the method next will implicitly close it."_ refers to input streams obtained using `getBinaryStream` or other `ResultSet` methods. So your conclusion is right, but your source for that conclusion isn't.